# Finding rank of image using nuclear norm optimization with linear constraints

Tags: convex-optimization, matlab, cvx

I'm trying to follow the theory laid out by the paper *Recht, Benjamin; Fazel, Maryam; Parrilo, Pablo A.*, [**Guaranteed minimum-rank solutions of linear matrix equations via nuclear norm minimization**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/070697835) to find the rank of the image below but it seems like I'm getting stuck with the linear constraint I'm supposed to be defining.

[image: The image]

The approach that I'm taking is minimizing $Tr(w_1)+Tr(w_2)$ s.t. $\begin{bmatrix} w_1&-X/2\\-X^{T}/2&w_2\end{bmatrix} \ge 0$ which is basically minimizing $||X||_*$ and adding a constraint $AX=b$ where A is a normal matrix (which according to the paper follows RIP and hence this should guarantee the solution to be the minimum rank).

Here is the MATLAB CVX code I'm running to accomplish the above:

```
X = imread('Lit Review/MIT_logo.png');
X = imresize(X,0.25); % To reduce computation time
X = imbinarize(X);
X = double(X);

rank(X)

m = size(X,1);
n = size(X,2);

% Creating a low-rank A just to see whether the output is throwing the rank of A
l_rank = 7; 
p = 12;
A = normrnd(0,1/p,p,l_rank)*normrnd(0,1/p,m*n,l_rank)';
b = A*X(:);

cvx_begin
    variable X_test(m,n)
    minimize(norm_nuc(X_test))
    subject to       
        A*X_test(:) == b;
cvx_end
```

Firstly, the rank MATLAB is giving for this image is 6 (it should be 4, I checked the SVD and it does have 6 non-zero elements, I'm not sure what's the reason behind this)

Secondly, the output comes around 14 to 15 which is nowhere close to the rank of any matrix whatsoever (the reason I created A to be of rank 7 was to see whether the output was due to its rank). Why isn't this working?

**EDIT:** Someone asked why the image should have a rank of 4. I'm attaching an image with red stripes depicting the distinct rows (at least according to me)

[image]

MATLAB is showing the rank of the above image to be 6 and the rank of X_test to be 166:

```
rank(X)

ans =

     6

rank(X_test)

ans =

   166

s(1:6) % s = svd(X)

ans =

  156.0389
   42.5381
   35.1799
   19.6956
    1.3728
    0.9778

s_test(1) % s_test = svd(X_test)

ans =

   15.9525
```

I tried `sum(svd(X)==0)` & `sum(svd(X_test)==0)` and both of them are giving 0, but after individually printing them out the 7th element of svd(X) is $2.4266e-13$ and the last element is $2.8205e-175$ (which show up in the matrix as 0.000 due to precision loss).

Plot of svd(X)(7:166):
[image]

Plot of svd(X_test)(2:166):
[image]

Comment: What makes you think the rank of `X` should be $4$? I'd like to see the singular values of `X` and `X_test` computed by Matlab's SVD function.

Comment: @littleO The image when resized and binarized has a size of $166 \times 320$. Hence the SVD is a $166 \times 1$ matrix. I saw that ``sum(svd(X)~=0)`` gave 166 and ``sum(svd(X)==0)`` gave 0, and this raises more questions than it answers.

Comment: @littleO check the edit I've made to the above question marking the distinct rows

Comment: Thanks. Can I see the numerical values for the singular values of $X$ computed by `svd(X)`? Maybe Matlab is having trouble deciding which singular values are nonzero, because probably none of them will exactly zero due to roundoff error. Maybe try plotting `svd(X)`.

Comment: In the image you have, the dot of the "i" in the logo is not perfectly square. Specifically, the two lower corners have a pixel missing to make the corners of the dot look "rounded". When I run "X = imread('mt26g.png'); X = double(X); rank(X)" in MATLAB 2018b, I get a rank of 5 not 4 or 6. I also get a rank of 5 if I run "X = imread('mt26g.png'); X = imresize(X,0.25); X = double(X); rank(X)".

Comment: @littleO I've made some plots and edits to give you an idea of the SVD's of X & X_test

Comment: @JimmyK4542 thanks for the observation. I tried different combinations of resizing in MATLAB 2021a, and I get a rank of 7 at the original size, 4 at 0.5, 6 at 0.25 and 5 at 0.125. This is getting weirder every second.